# HTML5 & JQuery - Not able to retrieve data from Data-* attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm learning the use of Data-* attribute in HTML5 and JQuery, about How to retrieve data simply from a div.

This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $('#restoreButton').click(function () {
                var sources$ = $('div').data('module');
              });

        });
    </script>
    <div data-module="Sources" data-module-id="sourcePane">

        <button type="button" class="green90x24" id="restoreButton">Restore</button>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It says the variable sources$ is `Undefined`.

I am using simple data() function of JQuery, but doesn't work. I've seen this is one of the Basic.

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: jQuery 1.4.1 was released in *January 2010* (and you're not showing how you  want to use this data).

Comment: Also you script should be at the bottom or wrapped in `$(document).ready() {..`

Comment: i was learning from this example http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter3/lab.move.and.copy.html .. it uses the same Jquery version

Comment: jQuery (with a lowercase j and a uppercase Q) has its own learning center http://learn.jquery.com, it's probably better to learn there than from a site using a four year old jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your version of jQuery.

Or check logs in developer tools (Ctrl+Shift+I in Windows, Command+Option+I in Mac).

You can check your variable sources$ with

```
console.log(sources$);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might need to update your version of jquery, but also try:

```
$('div').data('module-id');
```

The data method grabs the attribute, expecting the key after `data-`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the place to use this variable sources$?

You should to use this variable in the click event handler.

Or you should to define variable as global variable.

Comment: i didnt use the variable anywhere. it is just I am testing why I am not getting value from data Attribute . I placed it inside click event

Comment: How do you know you are not getting the value from data, if you are not using the variable anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Existing piece from original post appear to work ok, utilizing `jQuery 1.11.0`

html

```
 <div data-module="Sources" data-module-id="sourcePane">   
 <button type="button" class="green90x24" id="restoreButton">Restore</button>
 </div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $('#restoreButton').click(function () {
        var sources$ = $('div').data('module');
        $("body").append(sources$)
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/LZfUv/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but you are probably not loading jQuery properly. Check the the source URL of your jQuery script and make sure it loads. Also is there a reason you are adding the `$` sign at end if the variable `sources$`? It's uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

> it says the variable sources$ is Undefined .

Wherever it says so, it most definitely means you are trying to access sources$ from outside it's scope. You cannot access it outside the anonymous function you are defining as click callback.

Answer (score 0):

The `.data` method in jQuery 1.4.1 cannot be used with HTML data attributes. You need [jQuery 1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) (minimum) instead.

The example page you are working from, http://bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter3/lab.move.and.copy.html does not use the `.data` method to retrieve the value of `data-module`.

If you check the source, there's another external script, [jqia2.support.js](http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/scripts/jqia2.support.js), which retrieves the value of `data-module` using the `.attr` method (which is the workaround for working with HTML data attributes in jQuery 1.4.1). See lines 50 and 55 for this:

```
$(this).attr('data-module')
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3dP6A/